# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: bluetooth

Recently installed Ubuntu 18.4 on my Hp Pavilion G6. WiFI is working but Bluetooth toggle is grayed. Also,no Bluetooth device is showing in the terminal

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: rahul@rahul:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: I didn't ask for `rfkill list`.